# java.runtimeException only api 19 to 15

Tags: java, android, api, compiler-errors, runtime-error

when i install the app in api 23 the app runs perfect, but when i start the app on 4.4.4 the app crashes leaving me this logcat error. please help!!!!
pd: the app on api 19 has no image in the icon

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tirir_000.iavq, PID: 26678
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tirir_000.iavq/com.example.tirir_000.iavq.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070058
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070058
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2350)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
    at com.example.tirir_000.iavq.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make me guess - are You using AS 3.0 Canary XX? Try adding  `android.enableAapt2=false` to your gradle.properties file. More to read here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6mj8di/android_studio_30_canary_6_released/

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity.java` on line 33, your are trying to access a private android resource/drawable; android studio should show a warning by default on that line, as the resource is not accessible for old APIs.

An alternative would be to create your own drawable resource using vector asset or use any image.